# swagger file - marking fields mandatory and optional

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I am creating a swagger file. I have a POST method in which I have few mandatory and optional parameters in the body.

In the object definition, I have listed down the fields which are mandatory as below.

```
  type: object
    required:
      - firstname
      - email
      - city
      - country
```

But these fields are not shown as mandatory in the request body.

Am I missing something?  Here is the screenshot of Online Swagger Editor [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition is correct. If you switch to the **Model** tab you'll see the required fields indicated in the body schema.

[image: Swagger UI indicates required schema fields in the Model rather than Example Value]